# Haskell - Printing and returning a state at the same time

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I am writing a Brainf*ck Interpreter in Haskell.

I am trying to print `(chr (fromEnum $ getMem state))` which is just a conversion of a Word8 to Char.
Then I want to return a new state after the printing in a particular case which is

```
    '.' -> do hPutChar stdout (chr (fromEnum $ getMem state))
            hFlush stdout
            return state { prog_pointer = prog_pointer state}
```

I get this error message

```
The function `hPutChar' is applied to six arguments,
but its type `Handle -> Char -> IO ()' has only two

In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  hPutChar
    stdout
    (chr (fromEnum $ getMem state))
    hFlush
    stdout
    return
    (state {prog_pointer = prog_pointer state})
```

with this code

```
iterateBF :: BFState -> IO BFState
iterateBF state = case (program state !! prog_pointer state) of
    --some more cases here--
    '.' -> do hPutChar stdout (chr (fromEnum $ getMem state))
            hFlush stdout
            return state { prog_pointer = prog_pointer state}
```

I cant seem to figure out why I am getting this error.

After leftaroundabout and sabauma's comments, i edited my code to be

```
iterateBF :: BFState -> IO BFState
iterateBF state = case (program state !! prog_pointer state) of
    --some more cases here--
    '.' -> do hPutChar stdout (chr (fromEnum $ getMem state))
           hFlush stdout
           return state { prog_pointer = prog_pointer state}
```

using only spaces this time.

However, I get `parse error on input 'hFlush'`

Anyone know why?

Comment: Indentation! Indentation! Indentation!

Comment: lefaroundabout is right. All expressions of a do-block need to have the same level of indentation. Make your first line of the do-block line up with the rest of the code.

Comment: @sabauma aah okay. when you say line up with the rest of the code, which rest of the code are you referring to?

Comment: I solved the issue. I realised my previous cases had TABS instead of spaces.

Thanks for you input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on leftaroundabout's comment, you want

```
'.' -> do hPutChar stdout (chr (fromEnum $ getMem state))
          hFlush stdout
          return state { prog_pointer = prog_pointer state}
```

Note how all lines after the `do` are aligned with each other, not with the `do`.